# Is there a way in jinja to display a block in a specific page?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a `layout.html` page with a `<footer>` that I want to display in almost all pages using `{% extends "layout.html %}`. Only in the user profile page the footer will be different. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a footer block in the layout page and override it accordinly:

```
{# layout.html #}
...
    <div class="container">
        ...
        {% block app_content %}{% endblock %}

        {# block exists for all child templates #}
        {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
...
```

```
{# profile.html #}
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{# the footer will automatically be placed inside container #}
{# you can override app_content for the body #}
{% block app_content %}...{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}{% include "profile_footer.html" %}{% endblock %}
```

```
{# footer.html #}
{# won't be included in profile.html #}
<footer>my footer</footer>
```

```
{# profile_footer.html #}
{# will be included in profile.html #}
<footer>profile footer</footer>
```

For any page that you do not want a footer just leave out the block